# Ransack sorting not maintained after search, goes back to default sort

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, ransack

I am using Ransack to search on some data, however, what I'm finding is that the sorting is not maintained after a search. It reverts back to the default sort specified in my controller.

The scenario is: I sort by a column, let's say Revenue, and then perform a search, the sorting on revenue is removed and it goes back to the default sort I set in the controller.

Here is my controller code:

```
def index
    @q = Product.ransack(params[:q])
    @q.sorts = 'start_date desc' if @q.sorts.empty?
    @products = @q.result.page(params[:page]).per(30)
end
```

My understanding of the code `if sorts.empty?` was that this default sorting would not be applied if I had already sorted something. Is this not the case?

Thanks!

Comment: Hello, did you find any solution to your problem ? I have the same issue.. :(

Comment: Hey @EdgarsRozenfelds I haven't found a solution yet.. let me know if you do

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I found for this is by adding the `:s` field manually to the search form using a hidden field:

```
<%= search_form_for(@q, url: search_url) do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :s, value: params[:q].try(:[], :s) %>
  <%= f.text_field :foo_eq %>
<% end %>
```

By doing that the `:s` field always gets updated with the correct params when rendering the search form. It does not work when not setting the value manually because `@q.s` is an alias for `@q.sorts` which returns an object instead of sort string.